# Using WebCrypto to generate a key pair useful for both encryption and signing

Tags: encryption, rsa, webcrypto-api

In Chrome this fails:

```
window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
    {
        name: "RSA-OAEP",
        modulusLength: 4096,
        hash: {name: "SHA-256"},
    },
    true,
    ["sign", "verify", "encrypt", "decrypt"]
)
```

Why is this not possible? Why I cannot create a key pair which could be used for both encryption and signing? RSA keys by themselves do not have this limitation.

Comment: It fails with `Cannot create a key using the specified key usages.`

Answer (score 7):

[RSA-OAEP](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/#rsa-oaep) means that the encryption algorithm RSA and the padding scheme OAEP are used. OAEP is only specified for encryption and not for signing. For example, you can look into the [source code of Firefox](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/15f758f06d97ee3c4e382b174836395442c38f71/dom/crypto/WebCryptoTask.cpp#2290-2292) to find the corresponding check.

If you want to sign something, then you need to use ["RSA-PSS"](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/#rsa-pss).

You cannot directly use the same RSA key reference for both encryption and signing, and [**you should never use the same key for different operations.**](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/12090/13022)